Newton-Raphson Method for one equation and two variables
It is easy to visualize that $(2,3)$ is the root of the function $f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1-2)^2+(x_2-3)^2$.
I want to solve $f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1-2)^2+(x_2-3)^2=0$ using Newton-Raphson method starting from, say, $\bf x_0$ $=(3,3+\sqrt3)$ but find it hard to apply it directly, since here we don't have a set of two equations with 2 variables, but one equation with 2 variables instead.

For the first iteration step, solving
$f($$\bf x_0$$)$$+[\nabla$$f($$\bf x_0$$)]'($$\bf x_1$-$\bf x_0$$)=0$ gives no unique $\bf x_1$, unless we restrict $\bf x_1$-$\bf x_0$ in the same direction of the gradient. Adding the restriction results in a final form I have not seen in the literature (where generally $n$ equations with $n$ unknowns is explained).
What do you guys think? Am I wrong?
The fact is I do want to find the root of $f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1-2)^2+(x_2-3)^2$ with Newton-Raphson method for the sake of pedagogy. I think this is a great example in order to generalize the one variable case.
As I said above, the only way to get the first unique $\bf x_1$ is adding the restriction $\lambda \nabla$$f($$\bf x_0$$)=$$\bf x_1$-$\bf x_0$ with $\lambda \in R$ , so "my" final version of the generalized Newton-Raphson method for one equation with two variables is (just the first step):
$\bf x_1$=$\bf x_0$$-\frac{\nabla f(\bf x_0)}{|\nabla f(\bf x_0)|}$ $\frac{f(\bf x_0)}{|\nabla f(\bf x_0)|}$
It makes sense if we compare this to the one equation one variable case:
$x_1=x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}=x_0-\frac{f'(x_0)}{|f'(x_0)|}\frac{f(x_0)}{|f'(x_0)|}=x_0-sign [f'(x_0)]\frac{f(x_0)}{|f'(x_0)|}$
Do you guys agree?

Please check out the update... Thanks!

We know $(x_1 - 2)^2$ and $(x_2 - 3)^2$ are both non-negative and the sum of two non-negative numbers is $0$ if and only if both are $0$ and thus we can define a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that:
$$f \left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}x_1-2\\ x_2-3\end{bmatrix}$$
So we have to solve $f(\mathbf{x})=0$. But our Jacobian will be the identity matrix, and so when you start with any initial point $\mathbf{x_0}$ we have our next iterate as $\mathbf{x_1}=\mathbf{x_0}-J^{-1}f(\mathbf{x_0})=\mathbf{x_0}-f(\mathbf{x_0})=[2,3]^T$. This is our solution and we are done.
Now you might ask why we are done in just 1 iteration. This is because our function $f$ is linear and Newton's method relies on approximating $f$ as a linear function close to the solution and travelling along the tangent line at our guess, and since $f$ is already linear, that approximation is in fact exact and so travelling along the tangent at any starting point will lead us straight to the actual solution.


It might be a bit more "sporting" to use $f(x_1, x_2) = ((x_1 - 2)^2, (x_2 - 3)^2)$.  At least you wouldn't get the answer in just one step.
